# ADLA tools 2.2.6000.0 does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake

I have VS Community edition 2015. I installed fresh version of ADLA tools 2.2.6000.0 but it does not work. It tells me - install ADLA tools. How to fix it? (The previous version of ADLA 2.2.5000 has worked fine). See the screens.

I tried all combinations reinstall VS/ ADLA tools. It is not worked.

It is a pice of text from visual studio activity log (devenv /log) related to Data Lake Plugin:

> Importing pkgdef file
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\ADL Tools\2.2.6000.0\Microsoft.Azure.DataLakeToolsForVS.pkgdef
>
> Importing pkgdef file
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\ADL Tools\2.2.6000.0\Microsoft.Cosmos.ClientTools.Common.DataLakeServiceProvider.14.0.pkgdef
>
> Begin package load
> [Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.ProjectSystem.ScopeProjectPackageForSqlIPStudio,
> Microsoft.Azure.DataLakeToolsForVS, Version=2.2.6000.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f300afd708cefcd3]
> {CF041EA0-1A0F-462D-9B54-C32C2B35346B}
>
> VisualStudio 2017/04/17 12:10:55.634 2371
>
> End package load
> [Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.ProjectSystem.ScopeProjectPackageForSqlIPStudio,
> Microsoft.Azure.DataLakeToolsForVS, Version=2.2.6000.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f300afd708cefcd3]
> {CF041EA0-1A0F-462D-9B54-C32C2B35346B}
>
> 2401
>
> Not exporting category 'Azure Data Lake_General'
> ({fe594aa2-0c82-481a-99de-e99343ecea0b}) from package
> 'SqlIPToolsOptionsIntegration'
> ({317F9928-FDE3-410A-98A6-DF20D6CECCA0}) because the package is not
> loaded and no imported settings are available for copy-export.
> Packages will not be loaded for export during shutdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is getting sorted out, you can use Server Explorer as a workaround.  You can get to it from View->Server Explorer in the VS file menu.  Server Explorer may say that not all subscriptions are supported but go ahead and expand the Data Lake node under Azure.  The Data Lake node will load the ADLA accounts from any of your subscriptions